# Will a cast keep the low order bytes consistently across systems?

Tags: c, unicode, casting, endianness

Say I have a unicode character in `wchar_t x;`

Of course, the obvious way to convert `x` to ASCII is use the [wctob](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wctob/) function

But I'm wondering, since [the first 255 characters of Unicode correspond with ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), will a cast to `char` consistently work across platforms?

```
char c = (char) x ; // cast to char, this works on Windows
```

The question is, will a cast to `char` guarantee to keep the LOW ORDER bits, or will it possibly keep the HIGH ORDER bits? (I'm concerned about a little-endian/big endian situation here, although I realize if it worked on my little endian system, it definitely should work on big endian systems).

Comment: The first `255`? Isn't it supposed to be the first `127` only? (and by the way the answer would be different for either case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For the sake of brevity, I use some terms loosely. To avoid much confusion, one is **strongly advised** to carefully study [definitions](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/) of at least the following terms: ASCII, Unicode, UCS, UCS-2, UCS-4, UTF, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, character, character set, coded character set, repertoire, code unit*.

The code of the character 'Q' is 81 in both ASCII and Unicode.

81 is just an integer, like any other integer. A `char` variable may store the number 81. A `wchar_t` variable may store the same number 81. We *interpret* 81 as 'Q' in both cases.

It does not make much sense to ask how the number 81 preserves when cast from e.g. `long` to `short`. If it fits then you are all set. There's no endianness or higher bits or lower bits or any of this stuff involved.

When you convert *files* that store characters, or streams of bytes over a network, endianness and bits and stuff begin to matter, just like with files that store (binary representations of) any old numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` does not fit in a `char`, then the behavior is officially "implementation-defined" and is allowed to raise a signal. If `x` does fit in a `char`, then the value is preserved (regardless of endianness).

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> (1) When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> (2) [does not apply here]
>
> (3) Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

For maximum portability, perform a range check first and cast only if the value is in the range `SCHAR_MIN` to `SCHAR_MAX`.

(Others have noted and I wish to repeat that ASCII extends only to character 127.)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that the endianess of the system does not matter in this situation.

I found a really good [explanation here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14225/Endian-ness-problems). 
I think this should help rest your fears about casting.